# argparse: Default value for nargs='*'?

Tags: python, argparse

I tried to use this statement :

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--music', nargs='*', default=False, const=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.music)
```

But got this error:

```
`builtins.ValueError: nargs must be '?' to supply const`
```

what i want to do is :

- if `-m` is in args list but whithout any value, args.music will give me True
- if `-m` is in args list and have 'N' values, args.music will give me a list of all values
- if `-m` is not in args list, args,music will return False

the second and lastOne worked but, when i try to use const i got an error

Comment: Not really sure why you want the first point ("if `m` is in args list but without any value..."). Testing for `args.music is False` (or `not False`, depending on your logic) tells you if you're in the 3rd case or not. Then for the first two you only need to check the length of the list of arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [custom action](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action):

```
import argparse
class EmptyIsTrue(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if len(values) == 0:
            values = True
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--music', nargs='*', default=False, action=EmptyIsTrue)
print(parser.parse_args([]))
# Namespace(music=False)

print(parser.parse_args(['-m']))
# Namespace(music=True)

print(parser.parse_args('-m 1 2'.split()))
# Namespace(music=['1', '2'])
```

If you have only one argument to handle this way, then

```
arg.music = True if len(arg.music) == 0 else arg.music
```

is simpler. If you have many such arguments, then defining a custom action could reduce the repetition, and help ensure all those arguments are treated the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The following hack after the `argparse` section solves your problem:

```
import argparse

# Same as your code above
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--music', nargs='*', default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Modifies args.music: [] -> True
args.music = True if args.music==[] else args.music

print(args.music)
```

Tested in the command line, it gives:

```
$ python /tmp/blah.py -m
True

 $ python /tmp/blah.py -m 1 -m 2
['2']

$ python /tmp/blah.py -m 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']

$ python /tmp/blah.py
False
```

Comment: that is the solution that i've found, but i want to know if there is a possibility whithout extra code

Comment: No problems. Next time, please let us know you have a working solution .

Comment: There's nothing hackish or unseemly about refining the `args` attributes after `parse_args`.  Wrap it all in a function call and no one will be the wiser.

Comment: That would be my approach if I face this issue. I prefer a clear one-liner or a small function over a longer custom action.

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m', '--music', nargs='*', default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

if vars(args).get('music', False) is not False:
    if not args.music:
        args.music = True
print args.music
```

Output:

```
tmp:/>python arg.py
False
tmp:/>python arg.py -m
True
tmp:/>python arg.py -m 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3'] 
tmp:/>
```